# C++: class' name identical with namespace's

Tags: c++

Sometimes in my code appear a class (e.g. AI) that is interface for a lot of subclasses, whose names all contains base class' name (e.g. AIFighter, AIMage, AIThief...). The only logical thing to do is to organise it:

```
struct AI
{
    virtual void think()=0;
};

namespace AI {
struct Fighter : public AI
{
    void think()
    {
        //attack something
    }
};
struct Mage : public AI
{
    void think()
    {
        //burn something
    }
};

//...

}

int main()
{
    AI * ai = new AI::Fighter;  // It's my target
}
```

But neither it nor any other ideas I tried (typedefs, inline namespaces, using) are working. Is it possible? It would be useful not only in inheritance but also in any group built around some central class.

Comment: `AI` namespace with `AIBase` or `Base` abstract virtual class, and leave everything else the same (i.e. but the abstract virtual class in the namespace)?

Comment: @crashmstr That's what I'm using now, but I wonder if there is nicer way.

Comment: So what you are using is not what you have posted here? In other words, I'm suggesting putting the base class in the namespace but also renaming it to not clash with the namespace name. This is not what you have above.

Comment: @crashmstr What I posted does not compile so I must use BaseAI.

Comment: @Deduplicator Because those other classes inherit from AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the namespace name lowercase.

Comment: I am puzzled that I never thought of so simple and good answer! I think that I think to much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to solve your problem with a code example.  The reason is, you're clearly violating the reason we do things a particular way.

You have a namespace `AI`, and a struct `AI`, which unfathomably is outside of the AI namespace.

The answer to your question, in any reasonable terms, is to rename one or the other.  This is just simply bad design.

Comment: For me it's ok to have AI::AI, but I would prefer to typedef AI::AI AI; (which does not work).

Comment: @Dekakaruk The fact you are mixing class names and namespaces is the problem.  I advise, for at least a sense of clarity, to change one or the other rather than try and fight around it.